# Batch file subraction/substitution

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to decipher a batch file and there is a certain part of the code that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('getmac') do set "macaddr1=%%A"
echo %macaddr1
for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ("%macaddr1%") do set "macaddr1=%%A"
set "macaddr1=%macaddr1:-=%"
```

From what I gather, this piece of code is running the "getmac" command and then going through and setting each line and setting the variable v to equal %a, which is each line of the getmac command.

Since running the getmac command returns more than just the mac address, the second line seems to be going through and telling it to do the same thing but this time only assigning the first part of the line (which is the mac address in XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX " format.

The last part is the part I'm having trouble understanding. It says

```
set "macaddr1=%macaddr1:-=%"
```

From what I gather, this is somehow stripping out " - " from the format and just leaving the mac address in XXXXXXXXXXXX format.

As far as I understand, the : in there is a substitution operator, and according to the set command -= is supposed to "Subtract" variable, and the whole thing is in inside % %

I guess I don't understand this part. How does it know to subtract the dashes?

Or am I looking at this completely wrong?

Comment: It is not for substraction, which is an arithmetic operator with SET /A. What is is doing is a character substitution, i.e. replacing the **-** character with nothing, or the **$** character, depending which statement isn't a typo in your question.

Comment: The `-` is not "subtract" but the "search" string.  The full format is `%VARIABLE:search=replace%`. Here `-` is searched for, and replaced by an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

What your program is doing is not subtracting, that's the Batch syntax for **string replacement**. The syntax is `%VARIABLE:search=replace%`. The value before the `=` is searched for and replaced with the value after the `=`.

In your case, it's replacing `-` with an empty string.